# Dynamic Memoy Allocation of 2D Matrix of Characters in C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I cannot find my mistake(s), in the following piece. I assume there is something wrong with the reading, I commented out what I tried:

```
char **A; // pointers for the matrices
    int n, m;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%d", &m);
    A = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * n);
    if (A == NULL)
        exit(1);
    for(i=0; i < n; i++){
        A[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * m);
        if (A[i] == NULL)
            exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0; i < n; i++){
        for(j=0; j < m; j++){
            scanf("%c", &A[i][j]);
            // A[i][j] = getchar();
            // getchar();
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++){
            // printf("[%d][%d]", i, j);
            printf("%c", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: When I run this, I notice that the scanf() is catching part of the carriage return of the first couple entries.  Consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &A[i][j]);` (note the added space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider changing this:

```
for(i=0; i < n; i++){
    for(j=0; j < m; j++){
        scanf("%c", &A[i][j]);
```

to

```
for(i=0; i < n; i++){
    for(j=0; j < m; j++){
        scanf(" %c", &A[i][j]);
```

That space will gobble up and leading spaces or newlines or whatever from the  `scanf()` input at the start of the program.

And yes, don't cast your `malloc()`s as per the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't cast the result of `malloc()` (and friends).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int rows, cols;
    if (scanf("%d %d", &rows, &cols) != 2) {
        fputs("Input error. :(\n\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *data = malloc(rows * cols * sizeof *data);
    if (!data) {
        fputs("Not enough memory. :(\n\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // access:
    // data[row * cols + col];

    free(data);
}
```

Comment: Yet again, I get disappointed by C and multi-dimensional array support.  It just never quite works like you want.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Gaaah, you can have multidimensional arrays. It was you starting to use `malloc()`.